# Binding dependency property as target doesn't work

Tags: data-binding, dependency-properties

I make a dependency property like this:

```
public class MapShowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapScaleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MapScale",
        typeof(double), typeof(MapShowViewModel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Convert.ToDouble(1), OnMapScaleChanged));

    private static void OnMapScaleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mapShowViewModel = d as MapShowViewModel;
        if (mapShowViewModel == null) return;

        mapShowViewModel.MapScale = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue);
    }

    public double MapScale
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MapScaleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapScaleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and I bind that dp in XAML when defining ViewModel in Resource to element which name is "MyMap" and have a double type property named "Scale" like this:

```
<baseVm:MapShowViewModel x:Key="MapShowViewModel" 
 MapScale="{Binding ElementName=MyMap, Path=Scale,
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,     
 Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MapScaleConverter}}" />
```

But the value of MapScale Property doesn't change when Scale property of Map element changed.